# `git log -G my-search-term` in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, goland

How to run `git log -G my-search-term` in JetBrains IDEs?

Of course I know how to run this command in the terminal of the IDE,
but it would be great if I could use the git-integration, and the nice native
GUI to browser the results (commits) of above search command.

Comment: Git tab with Search field can be used for that propose: https://i.imgur.com/xMspQUl.png

Comment: @s0xzwasd it tried this before asking, but I think this only searches in commit messages, not in the code like `git log -G` does.

Comment: Gotcha. Please follow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109570